# Excel functions to return first row or first column from a range? (for a better 2 way lookup in table of data)

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

So I'm trying to do the classic 2 way lookup from a table of data, ie:

```
     Jan-00   Feb-00   Mar-00
Joe
Bill
Steve
```

So, I want to look up the value for "Joe" for "Mar-00".

This type of lookups are typically done using a combination of the INDEX and MATCH functions.  The drawback of this approach is that MATCH can only act upon a 1 dimensional range, so in a large spreadsheet with lots of tables, you end up having to define 3 ranges per table instead of one (one for data, one for header row, one for left column).

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
index(data1,match("Mar-00",getrow(mydata,1)),match("Joe",getcolumn(mydata,1)))
```

Is there anything like this in excel (or, an entirely different way of doing this, perhaps some new feature in excel)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the classic use for `VLOOKUP` (or the related `HLOOKUP`):

```
=VLOOKUP("Joe", mydata, 4, FALSE)
```

You can also use `INDEX` to get a whole row or column out of a range (or 2-D array) by passing zero as one of the parameters:

```
=VLOOKUP("Joe", mydata, MATCH("Mar-00", INDEX(mydata, 1, 0), 0), FALSE)
```

This is assuming your "mydata" is the whole table, including the row and column headers.

(Of course you also can also just do what you did above, replacing `getrow` and `getcolumn` with the calls to `INDEX`.)

Comment: I realize this is correct, but I don't necessarily know that I am going after the 4th column.  And using INDEX requires that I re-declare a range into which I am looking into for the index, as it can only act on a 1-dimensional range.

Comment: That's the point of my second example - to show how you *can* use `INDEX` to get an entire row (column) from a range or array. Isn't that your question?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct I just didn't read closely enough.  Very nice, thanks!  Don't think I've ever come across this syntax before, or maybe I did and just missed it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `offset` formula. For some named range **myrange**, the first row is:

```
offset(myrange,0,0,1)
```

Similarly the first column is:

```
offset(myrange,0,0,,1)
```

Comment: I've been searching for this function many times, glad I finally found it!

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the most efficient approach, you can use SUMPRODUCT to accomplish this request.  What you will want to do though is have a worksheet that contains the values and then reference them on your display sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('RawData'!$A$1:$A$4="Joe"),--('RawData'!$B$1:$B$4="Mar-00"),'RawData'!$C$1:$C$4)
```

Where:

- 'RawData'!$A$1:$A$4 is the column containing the names
- 'RawData'!$B$1:$B$4 is the column containing the desired header (which in this case is date)
- 'RawData'!$C$1:$C$4 is the column containing the desired value